# extract subfolders outside and rename if necessary

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I have a directory looks like:

```
dhcp-18-189-47-44:CE-06-new-stuctures_backup wenxuanhuang$ ls
DFT-00001 DFT-00004 DFT-00007 DFT-00010 DFT-00013 DFT-00016 DFT-00019 DFT-00022 DFT-00025 DFT-00028 DFT-00031 DFT-00034
DFT-00002 DFT-00005 DFT-00008 DFT-00011 DFT-00014 DFT-00017 DFT-00020 DFT-00023 DFT-00026 DFT-00029 DFT-00032
DFT-00003 DFT-00006 DFT-00009 DFT-00012 DFT-00015 DFT-00018 DFT-00021 DFT-00024 DFT-00027 DFT-00030 DFT-00033
```

And inside each folder there is there is a file called Li?Fe?O?_0, however, some of them might overlap, for example:

```
dhcp-18-189-47-44:CE-06-new-stuctures_backup wenxuanhuang$ ls DFT-00001/
Li1Fe5O6_0
dhcp-18-189-47-44:CE-06-new-stuctures_backup wenxuanhuang$ ls DFT-00002/
Li1Fe5O6_0
dhcp-18-189-47-44:CE-06-new-stuctures_backup wenxuanhuang$ ls DFT-00010/
Li2Fe4O6_0
```

Now, I want to extract the subfolder out into another directory, The first attempt I try is:

```
find `pwd` -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c "echo {}; cd {}; ls; cp -r * /Users/wenxuanhuang/Desktop/software/CASM_NEW/LiFeO_from_Alex_2015_08_25/LiFeO2-CE/02-refinement/CE-06-new-stuctures_extracted" \;
```

However, due to naming conflicts, some of them will overlap each other. what I want is: if they overlap: I want to rename it into something that is not conflicting and copy it inside....

Ideally, Suppose Li1Fe5O6_0 is already in the new folder and I am going to copy another Li1Fe5O6_0 into that, I would like to name the last Li1Fe5O6_0 into Li1Fe5O6_1 and copy that Li1Fe5O6_1 inside (in the future, we might have Li1Fe5O6_1 Li1Fe5O6_2 Li1Fe5O6_3 etc.) But if this version of code is too tedious. Then it doesn't matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this is the crucial setting: replace a glob pattern that matches zero files
# with nothing (the default is to *not* replace the pattern at all)
shopt -s nullglob

destination=/some/directory

unique_filename() {
    local root=${1%_*}_
    local files=( "$destination/$root"* )
    echo "$destination/${root}${#files}"
}

cd /wherever/you/need/to/go

for f in */Li?Fe?O?_0; do
    echo mv "$f" "$(unique_filename "$(basename "$f")")"
done
```

It works by counting the number of files in the destination directory matching, for example, "Li1Fe5O6_*". If there are none, use "Li1Fe5O6_0". If "Li1Fe5O6_0" is already present, the `$files` array will have one element, so the unique filename will then be "Li1Fe5O6_1"

Comment: This is incredibly complex, Thank you very much ! :)